# Checking the order of children of a div element are in correct order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object like below

```html
<div class="some class">
  <h3>This is H3 tag</h3>
  <h1>Testing H1 element</h1>
  <p>Hey this is p tag</p>
  <h3>This is H3 tag</h3>
  <h2>I am H2</h2>
  <h3>This is H3 tag</h3>
  <p><b>I am Bold</b></p>
  <h4>I am H4<br></h4>
</div>
```

Now I want to return true if the above tags inside the div are in the correct order. The correct order should be always
`h1`->`h2`->`h3`->`h4`.
we can have any tag (ex: p, strong) in between.
I got the above object in my javascript file, but not sure how to check if those are in the correct order or not.

**Note**: There can be multiple `h1`, `h2`, `h3` and `h4` tags.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried in javascript so far to accomplish this?

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to show an attempt and ask something more specific about your code.

Comment: Note that a page with headings in an order such as `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h2` is both syntactically and semantically valid and acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to cycle through the header elements in order, and use their number to see if it's in sequence with the last element

```js
function isInOrder(className) {
  let tagn = 0,
    inOrder = true;
  document.querySelector(className).querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').forEach(el => {
    if (+el.tagName.slice(-1) < tagn) inOrder = false;
    tagn = +el.tagName.slice(-1)
  })
  return inOrder;
}

console.log(isInOrder('.someClass'))
console.log(isInOrder('.someOtherClass'))
```

```html
<div class="someClass">
  <h3>This is H3 tag</h3>
  <h1>Testing H1 element</h1>
  <p>Hey this is p tag</p>
  <h3>This is H3 tag</h3>
  <h2>I am H2</h2>
  <h3>This is H3 tag</h3>
  <p><b>I am Bold</b></p>
  <h4>I am H4<br></h4>
</div>

<div class="someOtherClass">
  <h1>Testing H1 element</h1>
  <h2>I am H2</h2>
  <h3>This is H3 tag</h3>
  <p>Hey this is p tag</p>
  <h3>This is H3 tag</h3>
  <h3>This is H3 tag</h3>
  <p><b>I am Bold</b></p>
  <h4>I am H4<br></h4>
</div>
```